# Threejs - the cordinate position of lights seems to be inverted on some devices only

Tags: javascript, three.js

After updating from Three.js r89 to r97 the position of my DirectionLight's is inverted on some devices only.  Making my scenes look dark.
Applying position. `x *= -1`  etc it, however I don't on what devices to use this.

It could be something to do with the light direction in regard to the target.
Objects such as Mesh don't seem to be effected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest to detect which version of threejs is broken with this feature, and then look into changes

Comment: Can you create fiddle?

Comment: And what types of devices is affected?

Comment: Not a fiddle, a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) please.

Comment: It works in r92, but all versions from r93 thereafter are effected.

Comment: It occurs on a Galaxy Note 4